# setState and icon not working together - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, icons, state

In my React Native App, i have a simple FlatList. Flatlist's render item is a component "SearchItem.js" 
I need to re-initialize a state inside this component each time my component is called.

Flatlist

```
                       <FlatList
                        ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ paddingBottom: 30 }}></View>}
                        data={temp}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}    //SearchItem component                    
                        />
```

render item:

```
renderItem({item}) {

              return <SearchItem item={item}
                            onPress={() => {this.goToDetails(item)} 
                      ]  /> ;
            }
```

Click the down arrow icon and message expands. click "^" and it collapses.

SearchItem component below. Here state "arrowClicked" needs to be false every time the component is called. If we click the arrow icon and expand the message the state becomes "true". How do I re-initialise my state to "false" every time the component is called. Currently if a message is expanded it stays expanded. It should automatically collapse when the component is called again.

```
export default class SearchItem extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
     arrowClicked: false
    }
   }

setFullLength(bool){
    this.setState({
      arrowClicked: bool
    })
  }
.
.
render(){

return (

    {
      arrowClicked === true ? 
     <Icon type='materialicons' name='keyboard-arrow-up' onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength(false)}}  />
          : 
     <Icon type='materialicons' name='keyboard-arrow-down' onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength(true)}}  />

      }

 )
}
```

How do I re-initialise my state arrowClicked = "false" ????  Please help!!!

Update:
Actually it's strange!!

Example: imagine i search "hello" and 2 items in my flatlist render. I click the arrow icon on one of my message and the message expands. Now I clear "hello" text in my SearchBar. Flatlist renders again and all items are displayed. My message is still expanded (state: true). Now I search another text "hi" and 2 very different items in my flatlist render. I clear search text "hi". Flatlist renders again. Now my previously expanded message is collapsed (state is back to false). How??????? Focus issue??????

Comment: Please update your question with  `setFullLength` method.

Comment: Updated with setFullLength method.

Comment: @RakshaHegde What do you mean by "each time my component is called" in your question?

Comment: I have a TextInput which has a search logic. I type "hello" and it searches my FlatList for "hello". In my Flatlist "renderItem" is a component <SearchItem> (see my code in question). This component will be called SOOO many times.

Comment: Have you try this :- setFullLength(){
    this.setState({
      arrowClicked: !this.state.arrowClicked
    })
  }.   and onPress dont pass any bool flag...

Comment: @Savinder nope same issue. it's not re-initialising. Actually it's strange!! Example: imagine i search "hello" and 2 items in my flatlist render. I click the arrow icon on one of my message and the message expands. Now I clear "hello" text in my SearchBar. Flatlist renders again and all items are displayed. My message is still expanded (state: true). Now I search another text "hi" and 2 very different items in my flatlist render. I clear search text "hi". Flatlist renders again. Now my previously expanded message is collapsed (state is back to false). How??????? Focus issue??????

Comment: you should have to use extraData in flatList....it will help you to re-render flat list...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the arrowClicked from state;

```
render() {
const { arrowClicked  } = this.state;
const icon1 = <Icon type='materialicons' name='keyboard-arrow-up' onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength(false)}}  />;
const icon2 = <Icon type='materialicons' name='keyboard-arrow-down' onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength(true)}}  />;
return (
    <Fragment>
      {arrowClicked ? icon1 : icon2}
    </Fragment>
 )
}
```

Comment: I guess she want re-initial the state, not couldn't control state?

Comment: yea this did not work!!! it's not re-initialising. I click the arrow icon and state changes to "true". it doesn't become "false" again !!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution is to add a **Key** as this is Functional Comp and not Pure.
I just added a key to the parent  of my FlatList and it worked!!!

Comment: Maybe post the region of your code will be better answer if there have people face similar problem in the future. And select it becomes an answer.